# Centos 6.3 DRBD / OpenVZ kernel/userland issue

Tags: centos6, openvz, linux-kernel, drbd

When I start my Centos 6.3 server's drbd service I get the following error:

```
Starting DRBD resources: DRBD module version: 8.3.13
   userland version: 8.4.2
preferably kernel and userland versions should match.
```

I'm 99% certain this is to do with the openVZ kernel that I have just installed/using as the error doesn't occur if I go back to one of the other 2 from the grub boot menu. What do I need to do in order to allow OpenVZ and DRBD to work together on the same server?

For diagnostic purposes, the result of `uname -a` is this:

`Linux main2 2.6.32-042stab072.10 #1 SMP Wed Jan 16 18:54:05 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

---

If when installing DRBD I run the command:

`yum --enablerepo=elrepo install drbd83-utils kmod-drbd83`

instead of

`yum --enablerepo=elrepo install drbd84-utils kmod-drbd84`

Then the error turns into:

```
Starting DRBD resources: DRBD module version: 8.3.13
   userland version: 8.3.15
preferably kernel and userland versions should match.
```

So how do I specify that I want an even older version of drbd 8.3.13 instead of 8.3.15?

Currently using Repo:

`rpm -Uvh http://elrepo.org/elrepo-release-6-4.el6.elrepo.noarch.rpm`

Comment: Which repo are you using?

Comment: added the info into the body for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELRepo does still have older versions of DRBD, so you're in luck. Tell yum that you need a specific version like this:

```
yum install drbd83-utils-8.3.13
```

Comment: And use the yum versionlock plugin to make sure it stays that way. (At least until the host upgrades the kernel...)